# How to get a redirect chain working in Netlify?

Tags: redirect, netlify, netlify-cms

I have a `_redirects` file in my netlify directory structure

```
 /
 - site
 -- _redirects
```

**_redirects**

```
https://example.netlify.com/  https://www.example.com/:splat 301!
https://www.example.com/post/196 https://www.example.com/comic/post-name
```

**Problem:**

The first redirection occurs successfully, but the 2nd one returns:

> Page Not found

I have followed the documentation in https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/ but cannot find a cause of this issue.

I note 2 potential causes mentioned in the documentation:

> You can also add redirect rules to your netlify.toml file.

^^ I have not tried this, but since it reads "also" I assume using `_redirects` file should be sufficient.

> For Jekyll, this requires adding an include parameter to
>   *config.yml.)*

^^ I am not using Jekyll as far as I know, but my project does contain a `config.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding:

```
[[redirects]]
from = "https://www.example.me/post/196"
to = "https://www.example.me/comic/post-name"
status = 200
```

to **netlify.toml**

source of solution: https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to chain redirects on Netlify from what the docs read.

> The redirect engine processes the first matching rule it finds, so more specific rules should be listed before more general ones

```
https://example.netlify.com/post/196 https://www.example.com/comic/post-name
/post/196 /comic/post-name
https://example.netlify.com/*  https://www.example.com/:splat 301!
```

You can try without the first line above to see if `https://example.netlify.com/post/196` redirects to `https://www.example.com//comic/post-name`. If it does not redirect, then there is no chaining in Netlify redirects.

Comment: I tried switching those urls around as per your example. Unfortunately, the result remains the same. > Page Not found

Comment: I would make sure you have a `/comic/post-name/index.html` page in your build.

Comment: I am not sure what was required for this page, so did not set it up. Regardless, I found a solution (detailed below). Thank you for your help.